# jQuery: return false issues

Tags: jquery, toggle

I'm using the following code to show/hide divs which is working as expected, except for the fact it keeps jumping down when I click show/hide...

The JS fiddle is below:
http://jsfiddle.net/w3dwu0r2/1/

Although this does show the code, it doesn't really highlight the problem, as when in a real environment it starts to jump (I've taken all scripts out of the equation) - Perhaps a jQuery expert could assist, I tried adding  return false; - e.g.

```
$('.nav-toggle').click(function(){

        var collapse_content_selector = $(this).attr('href');
return false;
```

But this killed the script, I've tried various othe rplaces, but causes the script to no longer show/hide divs, hope someone can assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `event.preventDefault();`. Here is the code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.nav-toggle').click(function (e) { //<===== pass the event
        e.preventDefault();               //<===== prevent the default event from execution
        //get collapse content selector
        var collapse_content_selector = $(this).attr('href');
        //make the collapse content to be shown or hide
        var toggle_switch = $(this);

        $(collapse_content_selector).toggle(function () {
            if ($(this).css('display') == 'none') {
                //change the button label to be 'Show'
                toggle_switch.html('Show');
            } else {
                //change the button label to be 'Hide'
                toggle_switch.html('Hide');
            }
        });
    });

});
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/w3dwu0r2/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

Of course it jumps, because you use regular anchors with jumppoints (#collapse2).

I prefer not using href-attribute for that kind of data transfer.
If you have to stay with the anchor-tag, just use

```
<a href="javascript: return false;" data-toggle="#collapse1" class="nav-toggle">Show</a>
```

and change your javscript to:

```
var collapse_content_selector = $(this).attr('data-toggle');
```

if you dont like the javascript in href, just use the button tag

```
<button data-toggle="#collapse1" class="nav-toggle">Show</button>
```

works like a charm and no jumping :-)

third solution is of course adding

```
e.preventDefault();
```

in your js method, like Think Different stated in his answer